# Facebook comments do not show up when added with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, dom, facebook-comments

I am having a page with multiple facebook-comment areas, which are all different.

In order to save page load time, I want to make them only appear/load when the user clicks some button.

The problem is, when I've written the code

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://mypage.com" data-width="600" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="dark"></div>
```

in html, it all worked but when I've added the code via `.innerHTML` it does not show anything expect when I include the sdk after the html is manipulated. the problem with that is, that all other comment-boxes cannot be shown since the sdk loaded already.

How do I make all comment-boxes visible to the user when they click a button using JavaScript?

Comment: Sorry but your question is not clear!

Comment: i want to load the comment boxes when the user clicks a button.

Comment: So what's the issue? It's possible. Show some more code how are you doing this

Comment: But how is it possible? When the page loads i add the Facebook-SDK like described in the manual but it wont load any comments when they are inserted after loading the SDK.

Comment: that's why I'm saying you should show the code how are you trying to do this- `but it wont load any comments when they are inserted after loading the SDK.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´ve solved it like this. I changed the comment code to

```
<fb:comments href="http://mypage.com" width="600" numposts="5" colorscheme="dark"></fb:comments>
```

and after I´ve added the code i refreshed this particular section with

```
FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById("parent of commentField"));
```